# How to make a new figure environment that does additional stuff?

Tags: floats, environments, margins

Currently I have a document in which most caption of figures and tables is placed in the margin, using `mcaption`. But for some figures and tables I need the full width (textwidth and margin). Both settings are working fine, however I like that `\begin{figure}` and `\begin{table}` automatically assumes that it is a margin-captured-floatelement. For pictures over the full width I like to have a new environment `\begin{fullwidthfigure}` and `\begin{fullwidthtable}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[
    left=2.cm,
    right=6.5cm,
    marginparwidth=4.5cm,
    marginparsep=5mm,
    a4paper]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\margincap{\captionsetup{options=margincap}}


\begin{document}
\noindent Some text.
\begin{figure} [h]
\begin{margincap}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A caption in the margin.}
\end{margincap}
\end{figure}

\noindent Some more text.
\begin{figure}[h]
  \checkoddpage
  \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
  \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
          \caption{A caption for a fullwidth picture. The caption also goes all the way form the left to the right side.}
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
\end{figure}

\noindent Some more text.

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I've just seen, that the second figure does not take the whole width. Is this due to a missing package for the `+` operation? It is working in my other document...

[image]

Comment: You need the `calc` package for the addition of the lengths, otherwise `++` will appear, as you already noticed

Comment: You could also use the `sidenotes` package. It provides the described figure and table environments.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code.

1. As mentioned in a comment of @ChristianHupfer you need to call package `calc`. Then your code will execute your + as wished ...
2. You need to change the used `\textwidth` for your  second `\includegraphics` command to `\linewidth`.  The reason for this that you changed at last the linewidth of the used `minipage` to `\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth` (which is now calculated by package `calc`).
3. I added one version for the big image without environment `figure`, the second one with.  Please see the comments I added. because youuse class `article` you do not have to check for odd page or not ...

Complete MWE (see important lines marked with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[
    left=2.cm,
    right=6.5cm,
    marginparwidth=4.5cm,
    marginparsep=5mm,
    a4paper,
    showframe,
]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{calc} % <===================================================
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\margincap{\captionsetup{options=margincap}}


\begin{document}
\noindent Some text.
\begin{figure}%[h]
\begin{margincap}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A caption in the margin.}
\end{margincap}
\end{figure}

\noindent Some more text.

\noindent % <======================= no indention for following minipage
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} % <===============
 \captionof{figure}{A caption for a fullwidth picture. The caption also goes all the way form the left to the right side.}
\end{minipage}%

\noindent Some more text 2.

\begin{figure}%[h]
% \checkoddpage
% \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}%
% \makebox[\textwidth][\side]{%
\noindent % <======================= no indention for following minipage
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} % <===============
 \caption{A caption for a fullwidth picture. The caption also goes all the way form the left to the right side.}
\end{minipage}%
% }%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the result (page 1):

[image: page 1 of resulting pdf]